# How do I make prettier keep the component's props on a single line?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier, formatter

I am using the VSCode plugin Prettier as a formatter for my jsx code. when it runs, it makes every props takes a line on its own

```jsx
const Component = ({
    prop1,
    prop2,
    prop3,
    prop4,
  }) => {
    return ();
}
```

How do I make it keep them on a single line like this:

```jsx
const compA = ({ prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4 }) => {
    return ();
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Prettier can be told to ignore certain portions of code by inserting a comment `// prettier-ignore` just before that portion of code. However, if used in this case, it makes it ignore the whole function, which is not what's desired.

So maybe something like this would be acceptable:

```
const compA = (
  // prettier-ignore
  { prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4 }
) => {
    return ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prettier's algorithm is based on reprinting your code with taking a line length limit (80 characters by default) into account. When the line with the props is below this limit, it isn't split. But when the prop names are long enough, Prettier puts them onto separate lines. You can see this yourself in [this demo](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuc0DOMAEkC2AHAQUwF5MAKYTPAJwjwEYAaK2vAJmZroGZPWAWTAF8AlCQB8mYAB0omeZmpwYAV2pzgQgNyyhs2ZCgZsEfACES5SlwYAbaAHMAcgEMccPnTb2oztx5YeHz93Tzx+YNd3YTFiSRk5BSVVdSltXRBGEDoYAEt0ZFAXaloAdwAFYoQ0ZBAXW1KXAE8arIAjahcwAGtlAGU8LtzfZBhqFQ8QOBw2uAATOfmAGRdfFRcHOAAxCGocFxg8kZQXFRgITJAACxgcWwB1K9z4NEGwOD7q59yAN2em2pgNCtEDDNBwagwcqdBz7ZAAM3q4KyACs0AAPMydHr9fxLYZwBFIyZo9F9YYOWxwACKKgg8CJtmRIEG1HB1FqbRcs1slxowxg91ycxgV2QAA4AAxZLjg+6dPC1Ghwdk-QlZACOdPg0LoNROaAAtFA4PN5pclFrckpoRs4UhEUzJuCcLlRuNnRSqbT6YSHcSsjBuUKRWKkBwQGMXLlbBSAMKme1TNAAVkuKnBABVufrHcyfhMAJJQRawPpgai5PAwAglvowJpUxngoRCIA).

Said this, may I ask why do you want to keep long prop names on one line? If you don't care about the line length limit, most probably Prettier isn't the right tool for you. Its purpose is to facilitate the collaboration in projects and teams by taking care of code style, not to be a customizable code formatter that does whatever the user wants.

Comment: We just like to keep the component name and its props in the same line. it is the convention in my team. I've seen that there are options to force prettier to keep the props passed for rendering (`<Comp prop1={a} prop2={b} />`) on the same line. My question is whether there is an option that works on the component definition.

Comment: "I've seen that there are options to force prettier to keep the props passed for rendering" - There is no such options. Prettier's formatting isn't really customizable, and this is intentional, see https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html

Comment: I checked again, and turns out it's actually an [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-max-props-per-line.md)'s rule. not Prettier's.

Comment: I agree with @thorn0. Furthermore, condensing all the props into a single line poses readability challenges, particularly within the JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file named `.prettierrc` and enter this code
`{ "singleAttributePerLine": false }`

doc: https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration

Comment: Clearly states that: `This is an option to print only one attribute per line in Vue SFC templates, HTML, and JSX`, has no affect on props.